# 2014 TGB 550I LT 4x4 stutters after sharp turn (right)

Tags: fuel-system, atv

We have an ATV and we just got it up and running again (got scammed when we bought it). The ATV had been standing still for a few years. The ATV had a damaged front wheel and because of a bad repair job it had to be reattached properly.

The problem is that it runs fine, when going straight. Its fast and has no problems. Then **when you take a sharp right turn it starts to stutter, this can be right after the turn or further down the road. Almost like it is either running way to rich making it bog or that it struggles for fuel**. After pushing the throttle in and out a few times (slowly) it fixes itself and runs fine again.

We checked all the grounds and they are all fine. The ATV does not have a OBD port so checking codes is not possible.

Anyone that has a guess to what it could be? Or what I could try further to troubleshoot the ATV.

**Note:**

I am not an expert on "vehicle troubleshooting" so I am sorry if my question is not clear enough. I have tagged the post with `fuel-system` because my guess is that it is fuel related. Please feel free to change if  you think otherwise.

[image: Picture of the model of the ATV]

**Edit**:
The ATV uses injection not a carburetor.

Comment: Are you sure the engine is the cause and not the drivetrain? When there is a problem in a CV joint or differential it may also cause problems as soon as you enter a corner.

Comment: @MadMarky Im almost 100% positive it is engine related not drivetrain related. Cause you literally hear and feel the engine bogging. But of course im not an expert. I would also guess that if it was drivetrain related it would be more mechanically sounding noises? Or is this not a thing?

Comment: in that case i would also expect mechanical noises, but i'm just checking... What is the fuel level in the tank? If it's low it can lead to fluel starvation in corners. Another option could be dirt in the fuel tank.

Comment: @MadMarky Dirt in the fuel tank could be a possibility. I filled the ATV up before going home so the gas tank was full. Only thing is that if its dirt in the fuel tank, is it not wierd it only does it on right turns only? Btw driving for a long time in circles going right, the atv will eventually shut off.

Comment: Is the throttle cable binding? Does Wide-Open-Throttle have the same effect?

Comment: @NitrusInc Its not binding. It happends with wide open thottle and normal throttle. Letting go of the throttle for a bit will stop it from stuttering.

Answer (score 0):

if it has a carburetor sounds like float is in need of adjustment ..your sharp turn is sloshing the fuel to one side overloading allowing excess fuel to enter carburetor and flooding the engine to much raw fuel fouls the plug hence the shuddering...could also be excess trash in carburetor or your using alcohol infused gas ..it harms aluminum carbs almost dissolving which causes the float needle seat to stick like trash in the carburetor...hope this helps..get a friend or mechanic to pull the carburetor if your not comfortable to do the cleaning or repairs

Comment: Would the float not being correct mean it would overflow both in right and left turns? Cause it only does it when taking right turns. Not left. For example, turning around in circles steering right, the ATV will eventually shut off. Doing to the same but steering left, its fine.

Comment: it is possible that it may only do it turning to one side, also the fact that it has been standing for a long time also points to the carb, a good amount of bikes i have worked on that have been standing a long time and have spluttering and dying issues have been sorted out by giving the carb a good clean and checking float level

Comment: @RyanTheDirtMonkey Alright, Ill get the carb cleaned and tuned. Hopefully that will fix the issue :)

Comment: @RyanTheDirtMonkey Turns out it uses injection. Not a carb :-|

Comment: hmm, that makes things abit easier as well as abit more complicated, im not too clued up on injection systems on bikes, but possibly a wire touching somewhere when slight pressure is put on one side, but you say it does it sometimes after turning and going straight as well. have you checked for any water or liquid in the air box that may be getting ingested when turning one way perhaps?

Comment: @RyanTheDirtMonkey What i meant was that it sometimes does it when turning and sometimes a bit after the turn. Not like minutes after a turn but seconds. The thing has been sitting inside nice and warm for a few years. I highly doubt there will be any water inside anything but ill sure have a quick look :) I believe they already checked for touching wires when they checked all the grounds. But maybe not.